# Authentication failed, can cant upload files in UniSharp/laravel-filemanager

Tags: image, upload

i am using laravel 5.4 for my project. i used TinyMCE4 (UniSharp/laravel-filemanager), but i can't upload image in production site like www.abc.com/manager/new_post Here manager is not the root directory. When click image icon it failed authentication.

[image]

But in my local development it works fine.

```
Auth Config : 
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Manager::class,
        ],
    ],
```